# Nextcloud - Azure Mobile Engagement integration

Tags: ios, azure, nextcloud

Im trying to integrate the Azure mobile engagement platform with Nextcloud-ios project, but it's not sending any information to azure portal. I think the azure configuration is ok because I did it in other project and It worked fine.

I've just done the next configurations:

1. In AppDelegate.m in the method (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions.  I added the next line **[EngagementAgent init:@"Endpoint={YOUR_APP_COLLECTION.DOMAIN};SdkKey={YOUR_SDK_KEY};AppId={YOUR_APPID}"];** with my own collection domain, sdkkey and appid
2. In the main controller in (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated method, I added **[[EngagementAgent shared] startActivity:@"LoginActivity" extras:nil];** so Azure can create a session.
3. I also changed @interface CCLogin : UIViewController for @interface CCLogin : EngagementViewController but didn't work either.
4. I added all the frameworks that documentation says 
   [image: Frameworks]

Doing all this, any errors were reported in console. Just the message **[Engagement] Connection: Sent: appInfo**

I dont know if I have to make other configurations to the Nexcloud project so it works fine.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: You haven't shown anything. No code, no configuration, no errors... nothing. Not sure how anyone would be able to help. Maybe consider editing your question with more details?

Comment: thanks for the advice @DavidMakogon, hope it will help

Comment: I already solved it, i edited the question with the solution.

Comment: Please post as a proper answer - answers don't belong in a question. - there's no way to properly close this question otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved it

I just had tu put the init [EngagementAgent init:@"Endpoint={YOUR_APP_COLLECTION.DOMAIN};SdkKey={YOUR_SDK_KEY};AppId={YOUR_APPID}"] after temp & cache remove, that was interfering with Azure and Crashlytics frameworks.